# How to open and edit an XLSM file online

Tags: xlsm

friends,

I have a Macro enabled excel file. How and where I can upload my Xlsm file and do the updation. I mean, I want my HR people to do the updation on regular basis on this XlSM file from the branch office and myself want to see the updated XLSM file at my Head office. Is there any way for that? I think Google docs cannot be possible.

thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 0):

you may use database as a place that will store data. Your remote HR fill in excel tables then upload it to database (Access or MySQL or whatever) then you can download it wherever you are - this method requires writing macro that use ADO component - there is planty of tutorials about it.

regards
m